# Multiple root options in Linux command line

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, root-filesystem

My kernel command line looks like this:

```
root=31:0 ro noinitrd console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock2 rootfstype=squashfs
```

I think the first `root` entry identifies a disk by its major and minor device number and the second entry identifies it by its name. I can confirm that the `rootfs` is indeed on `/dev/mtdblock2` but I don't know how to interpret `31:0`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Different modules behave differently when you provide the same option multiple times. I know you can say `console=` multiple times, and you get multiple consoles (we use it for machines with main consoles on both their framebuffers and serial port).

However, you can only have one root partition, so `root=` almost certainly overwrites the previous value seen, almost certainly in a left-to-right fashion. This is corroborated by the kernel source, in `init/do_mounts.c`, function `root_dev_setup()` is responsible for acting on the `root=` option, and all it does is store the parameter key in a variable. The bootparam `root=31:0` is overridden by `root=/dev/mtdblock2`, or at least that's the case in the 2.6.25 source tree I just checked.

By the way, if you're competent with C, the function `name_to_dev_t()` in the same file is responsible for parsing the value of `root=`, and is very enlightening!

The `x:y` notation is standard Unixism for major:minor, which is the way Unices identify devices. Traditionally, *major* was an 8-bit number identifying the driver for the hardware, and *minor* was an 8-bit number identifying the device itself. There are two namespaces for the `major` numbers: character devices and block devices. You can see both by typing `cat /proc/devices`, and you can see what's currently active by saying `ls -la /dev`. Here's an example:

```
ls -la /dev/zero /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jan 12 22:01 /dev/sda
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 5 Jan 12 22:01 /dev/zero
```

The first column identifies the driver type (`b` for block, `c` for character). The two columns to the left of `Jan` are the major and minor numbers in `major, minor` format.

You can give `root=` any block device independent of its name using the major:minor notation.

The full list of device numbers is in your kernel source tree, under `Documentation/devices.txt`. 31:0 seems to refer to /dev/rom0, the first ROM card on the system.

Comment: This is a really good answer going well bejond what was asked. Is there someone willing to start a bounty for this?

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! As a junior kernel developer, the source details were especially enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Use labels (`root=LABEL=...`) to mount the file system with a label instead of a device name.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-boot-rootfs/index.html